# e. Create new variable whose values should be square of difference between variable1 and variable2

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to Create a new variable whose values should be square of the difference between variable1 and variable2, both are integer data types, I have cleaned the data for missing values, but I am not able to do that with below-mentioned code.

```
import numpy as np

df['new'] = 0

for i in range(len(df)):
    df['new'].loc[i] = df['imdbVotes'].loc[0] - df['imdbRating'].loc[0]


df['new'] = 0

for i in range(len(df)):
    df['new'].loc[i] = df['imdbVotes'].loc[0] - df['imdbRating'].loc[0]
```

---

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         4 
>         5 for i in range(len(df)):
>   ----> 6     df['new'].loc[i] = df['imdbVotes'].loc[0] - df['imdbRating'].loc[0]
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: There is proper indentation has been maintained. pandas library as pd already imported.

Comment: Your values are `strings` and not `int` or `float`

Answer (score 0):

I could not check the solution with real data.

```
# Set columns float type
df['imdbVotes'] = df['imdbVotes'].astype(float) # or int
df['imdbRating'] = df['imdbRating'].astype(float) # or int

# Do not iterate, use vector operations
df['new'] = df['imdbVotes'] - df['imdbRating']
```

Comment: I have tried given code but not able to convert strings to integer or float. so how to convert strings to float or integer.

Comment: Please provide errors information and dataframe sample

Comment: While using this code                                                                               1-           df = df.astype({"imdbVotes": int})                                                          2-            df['imdbVotes'] = df['imdbVotes'].astype(int)                                                                to convert string column to integer it prints below error for both codes:-                          ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,135'

Comment: Here is the link for data frame sample

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KvWzmqLaA_ZlKoKRSz0V1ycm4FIOdICQ/view?usp=drivesdk